# Check password stored with PBKDF2 with php

Tags: php, pbkdf2

I have a big problem, I have to write a php login page using an db where password are stored as PBKDF2 (with another perl script). When I get the password with a query I read this:
sha256:1000:2SeBDP88w4bqKbJaCJNpNuRHQhUM96X1:jgh/SZtmRWH5iDIwtXyFLtuuDf7YE+7HQEJZ4KFFNAg= (I know this password but I cannot regenerate it in php).

I tried with this script (get from php.net):

```
$password = "qqqqq";
$iterations = 1000;
$salt = "2SeBDP88w4bqKbJaCJNpNuRHQhUM96X1";
$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha256", $password, $salt, $iterations, 20);
echo $hash   // result a2ba3349194c38f828af
```

but the pass generate is a2ba3349194c38f828af and not jgh/SZtmRWH5iDIwtXyFLtuuDf7YE+7HQEJZ4KFFNAg=

who wrote the perl script that store these password told me "The passwords are getting encoded though one-way hashing scheme named 'PBKDF2'"

Some ideas? Someone know where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

- `jgh/SZtmRWH5iDIwtXyFLtuuDf7YE+7HQEJZ4KFFNAg=` is Base64 (the = on the end is a dead giveaway, though Base64 exists without a trailing `=`).
- Converted to hex, the value is `8E087F499B664561F9883230B57C852EDBAE0DFED813EEC7404259E0A1453408`
- This is still not your answer, but now we can easily see it is 64 hex characters => 32 bytes.
- You asked for 20 bytes.
- It also looks like your salt input is base64, but the function you're passing it to expects ... whatever the output of `base64_decode` is.

So, you need to consistently process the base64-encoded data.  And then you'll need to make sure that your hash algorithm, iteration count, and output byte count all match what the perl script says.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$hash = strtoupper(bin2hex($hash));
```